# I am Beginner in ROS.My USB camera is running on ROS.please i need a help, how to save an sensor_msgs/Image to a create file?

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am Beginner in ROS.My USB camera is running on ROS.please i need a help, how to save an sensor_msgs/Image to a create file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197751/i-am-beginner-in-ros.my-usb-camera-is-running-on-ros.please-i-need-a-help,-how-to-save-an-sensor_msgs/image-to-a-create-file?/) by [toupass](https://answers.ros.org/users/20866/toupass/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you need a "screenshot", you have two possibilities:

1. Use system-screenshot ability and take a screenshot of the image_view output.
2. Write a little Node / Nodelet which listen to a keyboard shortcut and then write the current image to file, for e.g. with cv_bridge functionality.

```
    void save_image(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr img, const std::string prefix)
    {
        // May want to view raw bayer data
        // NB: This is hacky, but should be OK since we have only one image CB.
        if (img->encoding.find("bayer") != std::string::npos)
          boost::const_pointer_cast(img)->encoding = "mono8";

        cv::Mat image;
        try
        {
          image = cv_bridge::toCvShare(img, "bgr8")->image;
        } catch(cv_bridge::Exception)
        {
          ROS_ERROR("Unable to convert %s image to bgr8", img->encoding.c_str());
        }
        std::string directory = std::string(getenv("HOME")) + "/catkin_ws/video_dumper_jpeg/";
        std::string filename = (filename_format_ % prefix % count_ ).str();
        cv::imwrite(directory + filename, image);
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [Torsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/20838/torsten/) with karma: 111 on 2014-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [toupass](https://answers.ros.org/users/20866/toupass/) on 2014-11-21**:
thank you very much it works successfuly

**Comment by [Torsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/20838/torsten/) on 2014-11-21**:
You are welcome. Then please upvote and mark the answer as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest that you take a look at [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-11-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Torsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/20838/torsten/) on 2014-11-20**:
After you have recorded a rosbag, you could extract the images using the image_view extract functionality. You have to run the following and you have to "play" the rosbag you've recorded.

```
rosrun image_view extract_images image:=/front_camera/camera/image_raw _image_transport:=compressed
```

**Comment by [toupass](https://answers.ros.org/users/20866/toupass/) on 2014-11-20**:
thank  you for the faster answer. unfortunately is not what i wanted. i will like to save snapshot of my runningcamera in a particular file(as jpeg or png frame). I will be very happy if you can help me.
thank you in  advance.